# Qual a diferença entre "margin: 0 auto;" e "margin: auto;"?

Tags: html, css

Como o título já diz: Qual exatamente é a diferença entre `margin: 0 auto;` e `margin: auto;`?

```
margin: 0 auto;
margin: auto;
```

Por que pode usar somente o 0? Qual seria a unidade desse 0? px? %?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, você precisa entender como escrever uma margem. Existem 4 formas de escrever a margem, entendendo que ela funciona em **sentido horário** começando pelo topo. Entenda que quando um lado não é definido, ele usará o mesmo definido para o seu oposto.

### Exemplo:

```
margin: /* top right bottom left */
margin: 0; /* margem de todos os lados = 0 */
margin: 0 1px; /* top/bottom = 0; right/left = 1px */
margin: 0 1px 2px; /* top = 0; right/left = 1px; bottom = 2px */
margin: 0 1px 2px 3px; /* top = 0; right= 1px; bottom = 2px; left = 3px */
```

### margin: auto;

Significa que o browser dará uma **margem automática para todos os lados**. A margem automática não irá funcionar em todas as ocasiões pois ela precisa de uma lógica para funcionar.

Por exemplo, em um elemento que tenha `display: block` como é o default de uma div, colocando `margin: 0 auto;`, significa que você dará margens automáticas na esquerda e na direita para centralizar o bloco horizontalmente na tela.

### margin: 0;

Já a margem 0, significa que você não quer margem alguma.

Para esclarecer o porque de o "0" não requerer unidades: **independe a unidade, porque em qualquer unidade 0 = 0**. Poderia ser 0px, 0rem, 0em, 0% e daria tudo no mesmo porque todos eles tem valor nulo. É diferente de, por exemplo: 1px, 1rem, 1em, 1%; estes resultados teriam todos valores diferentes, porque apenas o 1px é um valor estático. Os outros três valores dependem da construção ou de outros valores da página e podem ter resultados bem diferentes. Em conclusão, um 0, provavelmente nunca precisará de uma unidade pois o seu valor será nulo.

Comment: Quem quer que tenha negativado. Algum motivo em específico?

Comment: Excelente, exatamente a resposta que eu iria colocar. Só talvez eu alteraria um detalhe por simplificação: quando apenas dois valores são definidos, é dito que o primeiro será o espaçamento vertical e o segundo o espaçamento horizontal. Em questão de termos fica um pouco mais conciso do que dizer "topo e embaixo" e "esquerda e direita" (nesse caso em específico).  No geral, é exatamente isso.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Valeu. Realmente poderia ter sido mais conciso nesse detalhe. Por isso eu meio que disse isso antes, mas vou adaptar para simplificação.

Comment: Esse 0 é pixel?

Comment: @LucasCarvalho É como eu expliquei em negrito no final da minha resposta. Ele não é nada porque não precisa ser nada.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado Leon!

Comment: @LucasCarvalho Elaborei melhor o meu final, se ainda tiver dúvidas, dá uma lida lá.

Comment: Negativaram por algum motivo específico?

Answer (score 9):

Quando você coloca:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Você está definindo margens `esquerda e direita` do elemento para `auto`  e as margens superior e inferior para `0`.

Quando diz:

```
margin: auto;
```

Você está adicionando ao elemento margem `auto` para todos os lados. `(left,top, right, bottom)`

Answer (score 6):

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Define as margens `esquerda` e `direita` do elemento e as margens `auto` superior e inferior a `0`.

```
margin: auto;
```

Define todas as margens para `auto`.

Answer (score -2):

```
margin: [Primeiro parâmetro] [Segundo parâmetro];
```

Primeiro parâmetro = Definições verticais (todos os valores definidos aqui serão aplicados na vertical e/ou no TOP e no BOTTOM)

Segundo parâmetro = Definições horizontais (todos os valores definidos aqui serão aplicados na horizontal e/ou RIGHT e no LEFT)

Lembrando que, margin pode receber 2 parâmetros sendo eles os citados acima (Vertical e Horizontal) mas podem ser aplicados mais parâmetros, sendo aplicados no sentido horário.
Exemplo:

margin: 1 2 4 6 [Sentido horário: 1 = Top, 2 = Right, 4 = Bottom, 6 = Left]

Answer (score -3):

margin: auto; 
Quer dizer que todas as margens do elemento vão ser calculadas automaticamente
margin: 0 auto; 
Quer dizer que as margens do topo e de baixo vão ser 0px e a da esquerda e da direita vão ser automáticas

AUTOMÁTICAS:
quer dizer que o interpretados vai fazer um calculo baseado na largura ou na altura do elemento para que ambas as margens tenham o mesmo tamanho

isso é bastante usado para centralizar elementos, mas para isso é importante que você defina uma largura (caso você queira que ela tenha as margens iguais em ambos os lados) para a div ou o elemento que você quer centralizar na tela.

Comment: Nada diferente das resposta de 2017...