# Estrutura GRID - Alinhamento

Tags: css, html5

Não entendo pq não consigo alinhar eles ao centro (eu não coloquei nenhum valor dentro de `main`), se puderem me explicar este conceito, ainda está confuso na minha cabeça.

meu css está assim:

```
main .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    max-width: 800px;
    justify-content: center;
}

main .bikeimg > img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

meu html está assim:

```
      <main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="bikemake">
                <h2>Bicicletas Feitas a Mão</h2>
                <p>A Nimbus Stark é a melhor Bikecraft já criada pela nossa equipe. Ela vem equipada com os melhores acessórios da marca.</p>
                <a href="#">Ver Mais</a>
            </div>
            <div class="bikeimg">
                <img src="./img/bicicleta.jpg" alt="Bikcraft/jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="bikevantagens">
                <h2>Vantagens Bikcraft</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="bikedescription">
                <img src="./img/eletrica.svg" alt="Eletrica/svg">
                <h3>Motor Elétrico</h3>
                <p>Permite você viajar distâncias inimagináveis com sua bike.</p>

                <img src="./img/velocidade.svg" alt="Velocidade/svg">
                <h3>40 km/h</h3>
                <p>A mais rápida bicicleta elétrica disponível hoje no mercado.</p>

                <img src="./img/rastreador.svg" alt="Rastreador/svg">
                <h3>Rastreador</h3>
                <p>Rastreador e sistema anti-furto para garantir o seu sossego.</p>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Preciso deixar a grid alinhada ao centro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Os itens estão alinhados no `container`, mas o `container` não  está alinhado na tag `main`. O `container` começa na esquerda da tag `main` e aumenta até os `800px` que você especificou. Para o `container` ficar centralizado você tem que especificar isso na tag `main` (ou só dê um `margin: auto` no seu `container` [Veja](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206514/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-margin-0-auto-e-margin-auto))

Comment: Entendi, Valeuzão!

Answer (score -2):

certifique-se de max-width não está intervindo em justify-content. Sugiro postar o código das duas classes e o uma printscreen do resultado final para ajudar na solução.

tente adicionar `align-items: center;` ao container.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).